# Case Sensitive `os.Stat`

Tags: file, go, directory

I am writing a linting tool; one of the rules enforces that all linked files have lowercase filenames *on disk*, ie:

- `some/asset.png` == OK
- `another/asset.PNG` == Fail

I was hoping to validate this rule with the following code:

```
f, err := os.Stat("another/asset.png")
actualName := f.Name()
```

However the retun value of `f.Name()` always reflects the value passed to `os.Stat()`, eg: passing `os.Stat("foo.BAR")` will yield `foo.BAR` even if the file is named `foo.BaR` on disk.

Am I just approaching this problem wrong?  Is there another way to get the *actual*, case-sensitive filename on disk for a given filepath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you stat a file, the name returned in the info is the one you provided, as neither the `stat_t` nor `Win32FileAttributeData` data structures contain a name (in POSIX a file itself doesn't really have a name, it's just an inode named via 1 or more hardlinks) The actual name of the file on disk is stored in the parent directory. You will need to iterate through the directory entries to find the name as it's stored on disk.

You can either open the directory file directly and call [`File.ReadDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir), or use the [`ioutil.ReadDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) convenience function.

Comment: @JonnyReeves, you might also consult the `stat(2)` manual page of your system (if it's not WIndows) to see the `stat_t` structure filled by the corresponding system calls does indeed not contain the file's name.